# How to remove junk characters ■, �, □ in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

While loading the Streaming Data from Event Hub using pyspark Structured streaming, I am getting some junk characters like `□, ■, �.`
These are Unicode characters.
The Data Stored in Source side as `NULNULNULNUL`. `'\u0000'` is the decimal equivalent for 00 Char which is equivalent to **NUL**.
Provided, we cannot change/update data at source side.

---

Is there any way to handle such characters in Spark Dataframe?
I tried encoding options(UTF-8, 16) but this could not help me.

Comment: Those aren't junk characters. You loaded the data using the wrong codepage. This means you actually lost data. `�` specifically is the Unicode Replacement character, used when trying to read a byte value using a codepage that doesn't have a character in this position. You need to find the codepage that was used to create the text.

Comment: `The Data Stored in Source side as NUL` those characters are *not* the NUL character though. What does the original text look like? If the original text contains � it means the data was mangled when it was stored and the data is lost for good.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, How can we find codepage that was used to create the text. The Source is Oracle Database and on GUI i can see it as empty but when i am extracting the data and paste it notepad++, i can see value as NULNULNUL.
Even i checked in Event Hub, same data is fetched as '\u0000'.